# file:// links open in non-default browser on Windows. Why?

Tags: windows, windows-8, browser, url, default-settings

I set a new default browser and http:// urls open in it by default as they should. But I have some file:// urls and they open in the browser which previously was my default browser.

Why do file:// urls behave differently and not open in my default browser?

Comment: @w32sh `file://` is **not** the same as `ftp://`

Comment: Which file type you're accessing using the file:// url. Also, tell which browser you've set as the default.

Comment: I access local html files on my computer with file:// urls. Vivaldi is my new default browser, previously Opera.

Comment: Ok. Does Vivaldi show up in Default Programs, and did you set the default browser from there?

Comment: No, I set it from Vivaldi's own default feature and apparently it did not set htm/html files to itself. So I set it in Default Programs and now it works. Thanks. If you write your comment as an answer (check htm/html file associations in Default Programs) then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Control Panel > Default Programs > Set your default programs

Select your browser and click `Set this program as default`

This properly sets your browser as the default browser.

Comment: Thanks. I changed a bit your answer to be more generic, because the question was not browser specific and it applies to other browsers too. If the peer review accepts it then I'll accept the answer.